# How can the following line of code can create an object without the new operator?

Tags: java, swing

What I have learned is that new is mandatory  for creating an object.So, how does this line of code(from java swing) works?

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
```

Comment: It is calling a method. Something inside that method knows how to retrieve or create a `GraphicsEnvironment` object and return it to you. The method is taking responsibility for how the object is made; you are not creating it.

Comment: You aren't _creating_ an object; that function is.

Comment: so the GraphicsEnvironment class must have a 'static' modifier, as methods of only static classes can be called using directly the class name.

Comment: @trotsky No, only static _methods_ can be called directly using the class name.

Comment: This is an example of a design pattern named "Factory Pattern"

Comment: No, the `getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()` method has a `static` modifier.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the `static` implementation of the `getLocalGraphicsEnvironment` method which returns a `GraphicsEnvironment` type. From the [class itself, definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()) as -

```
/**
 * Returns the local <code>GraphicsEnvironment</code>.
 * @return the local <code>GraphicsEnvironment</code>
 */
public static synchronized GraphicsEnvironment getLocalGraphicsEnvironment() {
    if (localEnv == null) {
        localEnv = createGE();
    }

    return localEnv;
}
```

where `localEnv` is declared as  -

```
private static GraphicsEnvironment localEnv;
```

Comment: But how is *that* creating the object? ;)

Comment: yeah..exactly..the method must same code to create an object, right?

Comment: `createGE()` is the things that does it. Long story short, just because you do not see the new operator does not mean that it isn't being called somewhere down the chain of method calls. Although, in this case, new is never called directly, as the object is created using reflection

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code from `createGE()`:

```
private static GraphicsEnvironment createGE() {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge;
    String nm = AccessController.doPrivileged(new GetPropertyAction("java.awt.graphicsenv", null));
    try {
        // long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Class<GraphicsEnvironment> geCls;
        try {
            // First we try if the bootclassloader finds the requested
            // class. This way we can avoid to run in a privileged block.
            geCls = (Class<GraphicsEnvironment>)Class.forName(nm);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            // If the bootclassloader fails, we try again with the
            // application classloader.
            ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            geCls = (Class<GraphicsEnvironment>)Class.forName(nm, true, cl);
        }
        ge = geCls.newInstance();
        // long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // System.out.println("GE creation took " + (t1-t0)+ "ms.");
        if (isHeadless()) {
            ge = new HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment(ge);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new Error("Could not find class: "+nm);
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new Error("Could not instantiate Graphics Environment: "
                        + nm);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new Error ("Could not access Graphics Environment: "
                         + nm);
    }
    return ge;
}
```

While it never actually directly calls `new` to create an object, it does-so using reflection to create the GraphicsEnvironment for you. In this case, the call to `newInstance()` creates a new instance of the class that you are using UNLESS you are running Headless; at which point it is directly created with the `new` keyword.